# Facebook Graph API returns object with missing data

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently trying to get the total number of "likes" from a post.  If I query the post via the Graph API Exporer, the data is there under likes.data.count.  From my javascript application, the returned object only contains "id" and "created_time".

I have checked using the access token debugger and I have permissions to access user_likes and friends_likes so I am really at a loss to what's missing.  However, I do suspect that this is a permissions issue.  Does anyone know why I can't get the likes count on a post?

My query looks like this:

```
                    FB.api(postid + "?fields=likes",  
                      function(response) {
                      showLoader(false);

                      if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('Error occured' + response.error);
                      } else {
                        alert("got response: " + JSON.stringify(response));                          
                        likecount = response.likes.data.count;
                        alert('likecount: ' + likecount);
                      }
                    });
```

And my initialization code looks like this:

```
                    FB.init({ appId: '373915339387251', 
                              status: true, 
                              cookie: true,
                              xfbml: true,
                              oauth: true});

                    button.onclick = function() {
                        showLoader(true);
                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                                FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                                    login(response, info);
                                });    
                            } else {
                                //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                showLoader(false);
                            }
                        }, {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me,user_likes,friends_likes'});      
                    }
```

Comment: Hi? Are you there? I think I found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of response data received is this (Extracted from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552_10150189643478553?fields=likes)):

```
"likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Mia Lusiana", 
        "id": "100003399221230"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Habeeb Quazi", 
        "id": "525927716"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Mert Vrss", 
        "id": "100002500864051"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Nav", 
        "id": "100000757486687"
      }
    ], 
    "count": 8145
```

as you can see, `count` is inside `likes`, not inside `data`, so it must be this way:

```
likecount = response.likes.count;
```

`data` contains people that liked the post.

Comment: Hi Jorge, I have updated the question with my initialization code.

Comment: You have `scope` instead of `perms`. I don't know how FB works right now, so many time without coding FB apps but maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Ok, I've just read in FB docs that is `scope`. I don't know where is the problem then :-/ Sorry...

Comment: Ok, just checked a graph api response and I think I got it. I've edited my answer.